# How pyamf.amf3.ByteArray save to ImageField?

Tags: django, arrays, pyamf, django-models

I'm getting object 'pyamf.amf3.ByteArray'
How can I save it to ImageField ?

Answer (score 1):

**obj** - an object in django, data - array which get from Flash application
**data['finalImage']** - a pyamf.amf3.ByteArray and contains image
**obj.image** - an ImageField
**new_name** - name for a picture (without path)

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile  
obj.image.save(new_name, ContentFile(data['finalImage'].read()))  
obj.save()
```